# Input data for Canonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA)

Tags: r, factor-analysis, ecology, correspondence-analysis, mixed-type-data

I'm going to conduct `Canonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA)`. In the tutorial I've found at: [CCA](http://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2016/11/canonical-correspondence-analysis-cca.html)
environmental data are `discrete` variables with multiple levels within each variable (please check env.csv file in the tutorial). But in my case some environmental variables belong to `nominal` and some to `ordinal` data types with only two levels for each variable.  Can I do `CCA` on my data?Which data types are suitable for `CCA`? What should I do if my environmental variables would belong to different data types (e.g. `continuous`, `discrete`, `nominal`, etc. with different levels within each variable)?

Comment: [Some similar posts](https://www.google.no/search?q=canonical+correlation+analysis+on+mixed+type+data+site:stats.stackexchange.com&safe=off&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuve7o1_DjAhUQtIsKHQ_xB0wQrQIoBDACegQIBxAO&biw=1280&bih=617).

Comment: Thanks for the link you provided. If i understand correctly the posts are related to Canonical Correlation Analysis instead of Canonical Correspondence Analysis.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [*Gifi*](https://www.google.no/search?safe=off&ei=4MRKXa2yCOKlrgTXpaewBQ&q=gifi+nonlinear+multivariate+analysis&oq=Gifi+multivariate&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i30.4138.8024..11443...0.0..0.82.899.13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i10j0i203j0i10i203j0i22i10i30j0i8i13i30.E45qJ7PI37U)  there is an R package `homals`.